# Determining linear independence of three simple functions for a third order ODE. (2.9-7)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

This is a very similar post to one previous by me but I felt that not all questions were satisfactorily answered. But I am sincerely grateful to those who tried.

I would like a sharp independent eye other than my own to review my work here. I have a few questions I would like answered.

1. Did I actually answer/solve all parts of this problem?
2. Determinants of higher order (greater than 2) derivatives can be messy. Is there a less tedious more efficient approach to this? Perhaps I should have factored out the common factor $e^x$ before solving it?
3. Please pay special attention to how I established basis for my given interval $I$. I believe this may be my weakness.
4. I used the matrix TEX tag to form my determinants. Does an actual TEX tag for determinants exist?
5. How do I create a TEX dot (instead of asterisk) for multiplication or dot product?

**Problem in text:**

I need to show that the given functions form a basis of solutions for the given differential equation on any open interval $I$. But first I must use the Wronskian determinant to verify linear independence.

$$y_1=e^{x}; y_2=xe^{x}; y_3=x^2e^{x}$$

$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=0$$

**My Solution:**

$$W =\begin{bmatrix} e^{x} & xe^{x} & x^2e^{x} \\ e^{x} & e^{x}+xe^{x} & 2xe^{x} +x^2e^{x} \\ e^{x} & 2e^{x}+xe^{x} & 2e^{x}+4xe^{x}+x^2e^{x} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Below subtract row 1 from row 2 and subtract original row 2 from row 3:

$$W =\begin{bmatrix} e^{x} & xe^{x} & x^2e^{x} \\ 0 & e^{x} & 2xe^{x} \\ 0 & e^{x} & 2e^{x}+2xe^{x} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Below subtract new row 2 from row 3:

$$W =\begin{bmatrix} e^{x} & xe^{x} & x^2e^{x} \\ 0 & e^{x} & 2xe^{x} \\ 0 & 0 & 2e^{x} \\ \end{bmatrix} = e^{x}\begin{bmatrix} e^{x} & 2xe^{x} \\ 0 & 2e^{x} \\ \end{bmatrix} = 2e^{3x}$$

Indeed it appears that linear independence has been verified for all $x$ in $I$. I think?

Now let us superposition all functions and take their derivatives:

$$y_1=e^{x}; y_2=xe^{x}; y_3=x^2e^{x}$$

$$y= e^{x}+xe^{x}+x^2e^{x}$$

$$y'= 2e^{x}+3xe^{x}+x^2e^{x}$$

$$y''= 5e^{x}+5xe^{x}+x^2e^{x}$$

$$y'''= 10e^{x}+7xe^{x}+x^2e^{x}$$

We are now ready to substitute functions to establish basis in our given differential equation:

$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y=0$$

$$(10e^{x}+7xe^{x}+x^2e^{x})-3(5e^{x}+5xe^{x}+x^2e^{x})+3(2e^{x}+3xe^{x}+x^2e^{x})
-(e^{x}+xe^{x}+x^2e^{x})=0$$

$$0*e^{x} + 0*xe^{x} + 0*x^2e^{x}=0$$

We are now at the home stretch. Create an open interval $I=[-1,1]$ and select a few points $x_o$ and insert into $k_1*e^x+k_2xe^x+k_3*x^2e^x=0$:

When $x_o =-1$:

$$k_1*\frac{1}{e}-k_2\frac{1}{e}+k_3*\frac{1}{e}=k_1-k_2+k_3=0$$

Since this is true if we set all $k_i$ to zero we have established linear independence at this point within I.

When $x_o =0$:

$$k_1*e^0+k_2*0*e^0+k_3*0^2*e^0=k_1+0+0=0$$

Although this can be true when we only set $k_1$ to zero we still have the option of setting $k_2$ and $k_3$ to zero hence we have established linear independence at this point within I.

When $x_o =+1$:

$$k_1*e^1+k_2*1*e^1+k_3*1^2*e^1=k_1+k_2+k_3=0$$

We have now established linear independence for all three points within I.

This appears to be the solution. I think?

Comment: Just for the sake of accuracy. Remember that zero Wronskian may say nothing about linear dependence of functions in general case, but in case when functions are solutions of the same differential equation -- then zero Wronskian surely means that they are linearly dependent.